# How to prevent backgroundrb from starting multiple copies of the same task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scheduled-tasks, backgroundrb

Say, I have a worker that's set up to run every 15 minutes using the cron scheduling feature of backgroundrb. Then, say, if a single instance of the worker takes longer than 15 minutes to run, I don't want a second worker to be started in paraller by backgroundrb. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I guess I'll answer this one myself. The trick is to not specify `reload_on_schedule true` in your worker.